# Recuperar DateTime SLQserver en DGV VS

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms

Tengo un problema a la hora de mostrar el registro de la hora, todo funciona perfectamente, menos cuando la fecha es `00:00` (justo a media noche).

Ejemplo de este caso; `2018-07-26 00:00:00.000`

El valor se recupera bien en el programa pero a la hora de mostrarlo al usuario en un `dataGrid` solo muestra `2018-07-26`.

Apliqué una primera idea; a la hora de introducir el registro en la `BD`le añadia un segundo.  quedando algo como `2018-07-26 00:00:01.000`, haciendo esto si que mostraba en el `dataGrid` `2018-07-26 00:00`, pero no me sirve ya que altero el funcionamiento del programa en varias comprobaciones.

La pregunta es, ¿Como puedo mostrar esa fecha completa (con la hora) en el `dataGrid` en los casos de `00:00`?

Comment: Añade el código de cómo añades los datos a la DataGrid para ver donde tienes el fallo o que es lo que estás haciendo.
Una de las soluciones podria ser pasar esa fecha como string indicandole que muestre los segundos también.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La respuesta depende un poco de dónde estés definiendo las columnas de tu `DataGridView`. Si las defines en el diseñador, puedes acceder a la propiedad `DefaultCellStyle`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Después vas a Format:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y después puedes seleccionar un formato de los disponibles, o crear el tuyo propio:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En caso de que no estés generando las columnas desde el diseñador, en tu código puedes poner tu formato de la siguiente manera:

```
dataGrid.Columns[indice].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
```